# Make inline-block's align vertically too?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Sorry if others have asked this question already but I haven't been able to find any good answers yet or I'm phrasing my questions wrong.

Anyway, now I have something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/2nvwU/2/

Which does what it should, but I dont like the vertical gap which is between some blocks. 
What could I try to have the same spacing between blocks in all direction with a starting point in the top left corner. Because the blocks will be dynamic. I'm guessing columns is the way to go, but how can I load the blocks in the three columns from left to right?

I would like something like this:
http://www.googleventures.com/
or
http://dynamit.us/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Isotope](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFAQFjAA&url=http://isotope.metafizzy.co/&ei=NpIjUPSqA4inrAfp4YGADA&usg=AFQjCNHzbG2dSuid3yQGg-80of_sFMnasw). It is a jQuery plugin and its really good at doing what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

In case you have elements that should go across two columns, you will sometimes have gaps in the layout with masonry or Isotope. In that case, you might be able to use [this simple plug in](http://codecanyon.net/item/jquery-tiles-gallery/2281417) and change it to your purpose. Otherwise, I agree with Uzair.

Or - you do it "on foot", because [the dynamit code](http://dynamit.us/js/dynamit.js) is nicely commented and laid out :D